# Removing repeating substrings from within a string in R

Tags: regex, string, r

Is there any way (using regular expressions such as `gsub` or other means) to remove repetitions from a string?

Essentially:

```
a = c("abc, def, def, abc")
f(a)
#[1] "abc, def"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious way is to `strsplit` the string, get `unique` strings and stitch them together.

```
paste0(unique(strsplit(a, ",[ ]*")[[1]]), collapse=", ")
```

Comment: I think this should work for my purposes. I'll see if any other solutions get posted, but thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with a vector that has multiple such strings in it?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `stringr::str_extract_all`

```
require(stringr)  
unique(unlist(str_extract_all(a, '\\w+')))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this function based on gsub. I was not able to directly do it with a single regular expression.

```
f <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub("(.+)(.+)?\\1", "\\1\\2", x, perl=T)
  if (grepl("(.+)(.+)?\\1", x, perl=T))
    x <- f(x)
  else
    return(x)
}
b <- f(a)
b
[1] "abc, def"
```

hth